# React writing inline styling where it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this following react script :

```
var Bilder = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data:[
              ['1', 'http://localhost/foodoo/app/public/imgs/aichl.jpg', 'bild1.jpg'],
              ['2', 'http://localhost/foodoo/app/public/imgs/aichl.jpg', 'bild2.jpg'],
              ['3', 'http://localhost/foodoo/app/public/imgs/aichl.jpg', 'bild3.jpg'],
              ['4', 'http://localhost/foodoo/app/public/imgs/aichl.jpg', 'bild4.jpg'],
              ['5', 'http://localhost/foodoo/app/public/imgs/aichl.jpg', 'bild5.jpg']
          ],
      currentPic:[],
      display:'showBild clearfix dn',
      displayBg:'darkBg dn'
    };
  },
  showBild: function(e, data){
    console.log("PARENT COMPONENT SHOW BILD",e);
    this.setState({
      currentPic: e,
      display: 'showBild clearfix db',
      displayBg: 'darkBg db'
    });
    $('.showBild').attr('style', ''); // Hack
    $('.darkBg').attr('style', ''); // Hack
  },
  hide: function(){
    console.log("PARENT COMPONENT HIDE BILD");
    this.setState({
      display: 'showBild clearfix dn',
      displayBg: 'darkBg dn'
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SingleBild data={this.state.data} chosenBild={this.showBild} />
        <BildDetail hide={this.hide} data={this.state.currentPic} display={this.state.display} displayBg={this.state.displayBg} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SingleBild = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      bild:[]
    };
  },
  showBild: function(data, e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked a");
    this.props.chosenBild(data);
  },
  render: function() {
    var scopeThis = this;
    var displayBild = function(bild){
         return <li><img src={bild[1]} alt="" /><span>{bild[2]}</span><a onClick={scopeThis.showBild.bind(null, bild)} href="#"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
    };
    return (
      <ul className="dashboardUl bilder clearfix">
        <h2>Gemeldete Bilder:</h2>
        {this.props.data.map(displayBild)}
      </ul>
    );
  }

});
var BildDetail  = React.createClass({
  hide: function(){
    this.props.hide();
  },
  render: function() {
    var scopeThis = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.props.display}>
          <img src={this.props.data[1]} alt="" />
          <span>{this.props.data[2]}</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-ban"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.hide} className={this.props.displayBg}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Bilder />, document.getElementById('bilder'));
```

The main functionality is as following:

The parentcomponent `<Bilder />` has 2 child component `<SingleBild />` and `<BildDetail />` .  has 4 initial states, `data:` which is an array and contains dummy entries with some img path, `currentPic:` which gets filled when some action happens, `display:` + `displayBg` which contains some classes to style an element and hide it

In the `<SingleBild />` component the state array of the parent component has been passed as a prop. Now it gets mapped and rendered out to display seperate elements. Those elements have content which consist of an img and 2 icons. One icon is clickable.

The clickable icon calls a function which passes some content to the parent component in which another function gets called to alter the state and set state `currentPic, display and displayBg`.

currentPic now contains an array with the img src and everything needed. The other two states got changed with one class from "dn" to "db" (=from display none class to display block class)

Now a div gets shown above the content containg an img and two more icons. behind the div there is a 100% width and height black background which has an onClick function.
The onClick function is called hide, it changes the state back from "db" to "dn" (=from display block class to display none class)

Somehow react doesnt only change the class but also creates an inline style which looks liek that style="display:none"

So when I click the icon to show the popup again the classes get changed fine but the inline style attribute is still there and overwritting all class styles...

Comment: Why not use `.removeAttr('style')` instead of setting style to an empty string?

Comment: because I don't want to use any inline style attributes at all - the way I did it is some hacky solution that shoudlnt be necessary. As you see in the code, the state updates the prop of a child component which then again changes the class of the element from a class that contains either display block or display none

Weirdly when the display none class is being applied - react adds an inline style with display none that will overwrite any future class changes

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle to help demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Hello, since js fiddle is using an out of date version I have troubles to display it there.

If you create any local html file enable the live jsx transformer then include a script tag with my content you can easily recreate my code :)